# System.Reactive - Buffer/group immediately available values of an Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

let's say you have an IObservable<T> that may supply a few values immediately, and some being pushed continously:

```
    var immediate_values = new [] { "curerntly", "available", "values" }.ToObservable();
    var future_values = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(x => "new value!");

    IObservable<string> input = immediate_values.Concat(future_values);
```

Is there any way to transform input into an IObservable<string[]>, where the first array being pushed consists of all immediately available values, and each subsequent array consists of only 1 value (each one being pushed thereafter)?
Above is just example data naturally, this would need to work on any IObservable>T> without knowing the individual input streams.

```
    IObservable<string[]> buffered = input.BufferSomehow();
    // should push values:
    // First value: string[] = ["currently", "available", "values"]
    // Second value: string[] = ["new value!"]
    // Third value: string[] = ["new value!"]
    // .....
```

I've thought of the .Buffer() function of course, but I don't really want to buffer by any particular TimeSpan, and can't think of any way to produce an observable with buffer window closing signals.

Can anyone think of a reasonable way to achieve this, or is this not really possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to distinguish between the on-start-up values of an observable and the subsequent values. My suggestion would be to infer it:

```
var autoBufferedInput1 = input.Publish(_input => _input
   .Buffer(_input.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1)))
   .Select(l => l.ToArray())
);
```

This sets your buffer boundary to a rolling, extending window of .1 seconds: Each time a value comes in, it extends the window to .1 seconds from the time the value came in, and adds the value to the buffer. If .1 seconds go by with no values, then the buffer is flushed out.

This will have the side-effect that if you have near-simultaneous "hot" values (within .1 seconds of each other), then those will be buffered together. If that's undesired, you can `Switch` out, though that makes things more complicated:

```
var autoBufferedInput2 = input.Publish(_input =>
    _input.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1)).Publish(_boundary => _boundary
        .Take(1)
        .Select(_ => _input.Select(s => new[] { s }))
        .StartWith(_input
            .Buffer(_boundary)
            .Select(l => l.ToArray())
        )
        .Switch()
    )
);
```

`autoBufferedInput2` uses the .1 second inference method until the first buffered list, then switches to simply selecting out and wrapping values in an array.

---

**EDIT**: If you want an absolute 1 second gate as well, then the snippets would look like this:

```
var autoBufferedInput1 = input.Publish(_input => _input
    .Buffer(
        Observable.Merge(
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => Unit.Default),
            _input.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1)).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
        )
    )
    .Select(l => l.ToArray())
);

var autoBufferedInput2 = input.Publish(_input =>
    Observable.Merge(
        _input.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1)).Select(_ => Unit.Default),
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    )
    .Publish(_boundary => _boundary
        .Take(1)
        .Select(_ => _input.Select(s => new[] { s }))
        .StartWith(_input
            .Buffer(_boundary)
            .Select(l => l.ToArray())
        )
        .Switch()
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Shlomo, interesting approach! I think your first code snippet would potentially be delayed indefinitely though if the stream constantly kept pushing out values in a frequency of less than 0.1 seconds, right? Would there be an easy way to implement a threshold condition - e.g. roll window every 0.1 seconds, but don't ever aggregate for longer than a second in total at a time or such?

Comment: Added that logic, though as written, for `autoBufferedInput1` it would only apply for the first window.

Answer (score 0):

For any `IObservable<T>`, you'd need to do:

```
var sequence = ongoingSequence.StartWith(initialSequence);
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks - unfortunately that would only for the specific example / when you have direct control of how the input observable is set up. I'd need a solution that works for any general IObservable&lt;T&gt; without any control or knowledge of the implementation of the specific stream

Comment: So, you want it to work for `Observable<T>` rather than `Observable<string[]>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the fact that the immediately available values are propagated synchronously during the subscription, and toggle some switch after the `Subscribe` method returns. The implementation below is based on this idea. During the subscription all incoming messages are buffered, after the subscription the buffer is emitted, and after that all future incoming messages are emitted immediately one by one.

```
public static IObservable<T[]> BufferImmediatelyAvailable<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<T[]>(observer =>
    {
        var buffer = new List<T>();

        var subscription = source.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            if (buffer != null)
                buffer.Add(x);
            else
                observer.OnNext(new[] { x });
        }, ex =>
        {
            buffer = null;
            observer.OnError(ex);
        }, () =>
        {
            if (buffer != null)
            {
                var output = buffer.ToArray();
                buffer = null;
                observer.OnNext(output);
            }
            observer.OnCompleted();
        });

        if (buffer != null)
        {
            var output = buffer.ToArray();
            buffer = null;
            observer.OnNext(output);
        }

        return subscription;
    });
}
```